# Set height of ckeditor using surveyjs-widgets and survey-react

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, surveyjs

I have a reactjs web application in which I have following lines of code

File : index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

File : survey.tsx

```
import * as SurveyReact from 'survey-react';
import * as widgets from "surveyjs-widgets";

widgets.ckeditor(SurveyReact);
```

How I can customize *config* properties or toolbar elements of ckeditor in this scenerio?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to change some config properties like following, but I want to do it by passing config object to widget or by accessing through SurveyReact object.

File : index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   CKEDITOR.config.height = 300;
</script>
```